# Get value by key of object field in a MongoDB document or default value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in a MongoDB database. Each document has (among others) one object field that looks like this:

```
name: {
    "en-US": "Foo",
    "es-ES": "Bar"
    ...
}
```

The `en-US` key is guaranteed to exist, but any other keys/values are not.

Is there a way I can query the documents in such a way that the result would contain the field `name` and the value of that field would be either the language I passed (let it be `es-ES`) or if that key doesn't exist, the value of `en-US`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            short_id: 1,
            name: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: ["$name.es-ES", undefined]
                    },
                    then: '$name.en-EN',
                    else: '$name.es-ES'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```